# is there a built-in way to set a timeout value for webclient?

Tags: c#, .net, rest

Is there a built-in way to set a timeout value for WebClient? My WebClient is timing out on a long-running REST call.  I googled for ways to increase the request timeout value for WebClient calls but I only found examples which created an extension class for WebClient.  It seems like .NET would have a built-in way to extend the timeout value for WebClient requests.  Do you know how to do this?

Comment: HttpClient is not an option instead of WebClient?

Comment: thanks khat I switched from webclient to httpclient based on your recommendation.  what is the history of these 2 implementations?  for example, was webclient the original option .net provided for calling rest services, but then they updated httpclient later on to be the better client for this?

Comment: you may look at following: http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/webclient-vs-httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest/